# Why does cron start twice every night?

Tags: 18.04, bash, cron

I run on Ubuntu 18.04.2 and use cron for various script management and watchdog. In particular I restart some daemontools process every night.
For some unknown reason, every morning I find a double instance of cron

```
ps -A | grep cron
```

I can kill it manually and could automate it of course, but I would'nt understand why.

I looked into /etc/cron.* and could not find unexpected double scripts.

Which part of Ubuntu rules cron?

```
pgrep -a cron;
1221 /usr/sbin/cron -f
3811 /usr/sbin/CRON -f

systemctl status cron.service
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-04-17 00:50:51 UTC; 1 day 13h ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1221 (cron)
    Tasks: 16
   Memory: 544.0M
      CPU: 1d 11h 10min 53.180s
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ├─ 1221 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           ├─ 3811 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
           ├─ 3814 /bin/sh -c /root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh
           ├─ 3815 /bin/sh /root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh
           ├─ 3816 /bin/sh /root/civilia/Candiac/tech/parkingMonitoring-LoRa/prediction.sh
           ├─ 3817 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --file=/root/civilia/Candiac/tech/parkingMonitoring-LoRa//prediction.R
           ├─ 6069 /bin/sh -c /root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh
           ├─ 6070 /bin/sh /root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh
           ├─ 6071 /bin/sh /root/civilia/Candiac/tech/parkingMonitoring-LoRa/prediction.sh
           ├─ 6073 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --file=/root/civilia/Candiac/tech/parkingMonitoring-LoRa//prediction.R
           ├─27218 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
           ├─27221 /bin/sh -c /root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh
           ├─27222 /bin/sh /root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh
           ├─27538 /bin/bash /root/civilia/STS/gtfs-rt/scripts/watchDog.sh
           ├─28014 bash /var/svc.d/STSAG-create-gtfs-rt/esclave.sh rs
           └─28028 sleep 5

Apr 18 14:36:02 VM-001 CRON[24186]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 14:36:02 VM-001 CRON[24187]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 14:36:02 VM-001 CRON[24188]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/public_html/portail-Civilia/cron/disconnectionTracker.php > /dev/null )
Apr 18 14:36:02 VM-001 CRON[24189]: (root) CMD (/root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh)
Apr 18 14:36:02 VM-001 CRON[24186]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 14:36:10 VM-001 CRON[24187]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 14:38:02 VM-001 CRON[27217]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 14:38:02 VM-001 CRON[27219]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/public_html/portail-Civilia/cron/disconnectionTracker.php > /dev/null )
Apr 18 14:38:02 VM-001 CRON[27218]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 14:38:02 VM-001 CRON[27221]: (root) CMD (/root/civilia/general/admin_server/minuteRoutine.sh)
```

Comment: please add the results of the command too. systemd rules cron :+

Comment: On thing are the scripts that cron starts and other cron itself. Please add the output of your command or probably better this one: `pgrep -a cron; systemctl status cron.service`.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/CRON` is running as process 3811. Take a look at that file with the `file` command and maybe `strings -n 6 | less` to see what it is/what's in it. My kubuntu 18.04 system doesn't have that file, so it's probably some sort of script that works with the actual `cron` - `/usr/sbin/cron`. It has a higher process number, so it may have been started later than `cron` (not guaranteed - process IDs wrap).

Comment: If `cron` were really running twice every night, it would do all the jobs in `crontab` twice. If you create a script that just appends the output of `date` to a file and add it to `crontab` as a daily job, you'll see immediately (the next day) exactly when it ran and if it ran more than once in the same day.

Comment: Thank you Joe, the script that seems to be running twice is a minute-wise one (minuteRoutine.sh). It looks like it started as I included flock -xn for each process.